# row contains multiple values, select for only one value in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame (df) of

```
A     AA     B        C      D
23    1    1,0,0    0,1,0    0
10    0    0,0,0      1      1,1
```

I would like the following df2

```
A     AA       B        C      D
23     1       1        1      0
10     0       0        1      1
```

I really don't have any idea how to even begin coding this. But my shot in the dark is

```
df2 <- df1 %>% filter_at(vars(B, C, D), any_var(. !=0))
```

I get the following error: error in is.data.frame(x): object 'B' not found

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciate as I am new to all of this, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(D) %>%
  separate_rows(AA, B, C) %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  summarise(across(AA:D, ~ max(.x)))


# A tibble: 2 x 5
      A    AA B     C     D    
  <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1    10     0 0     1     1    
2    23     1 1     1     0
```

Comment: This works as well.  Sidenote, this code is very useful when I apply it to a data frame that does not need a group_by code.  It preserves the values in columns that are nonnumerical.  Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure I imagined you wanted to extract the maximum values.

Comment: Good idea, @AnoushiravanR, thank you. But it works only if the number of items per cell is compatible.

Comment: I had similar problem when I tried to separate delimited values and that's why I had 2 steps of `separate_rows` but I'm afraid I need a data set that best represents your real data set, if I am to come up with something more generalized.

Answer (score 1):

```
df$B<-as.character(df$B)
df$B[df$B == "1,0,0"] <- "1"
df$B[df$B == "0,0,0"] <- "0"
df$B<- as.factor(df$B)

df$C<-as.character(df$B)
df$C[df$C == "0,1,0"] <- "1"
df$C<- as.factor(df$B)

df$D<-as.character(df$D)
df$D[df$D == "1,1"] <- "1"
df$D<- as.factor(df$D)
```

Ok, I think I figured it out.  This may not be the most efficient way to code for this, but it does get the job done and changes the values in df to reflect what I wanted for df2.

If I needed to keep the original df and create a new df2 then I would just put this code first.

```
df2<-df
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a way with "base R". Explanation:  `strsplit` splits at the comma and `max` finds the maximum value. Function `sapply` does vectorization.

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
A     AA     B        C      D
23    1    1,0,0    0,1,0    0
10    0    0,0,0      1      1,1",
header = TRUE)

f <- function(x) {
  if (is.character(x)) {
    as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(x, ","), max))
  } else {
    x
  }
}

df2 <- sapply(df1, f)
df2
```

If the type of non-numerical cells needs to be kept, just remove `as.numeric()`. To be precise: in the above, `max` works alphabetically at the character level, not with numbers.

As an alternative, one can also do this with regular expressions.

Comment: This works as well. And is really helpful when I have more than just two rows.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

And here a version with regular expressions, I am myself curious how to improve this:

```
f <- function(x) {
  x <- gsub("0,", "", x)
  x <- gsub(",0", "", x)
  x <- gsub(",[1-9].*", "", x)
  as.numeric(x)
}

df2 <- sapply(df1, f)
df2
```